# My y axis labels are not shown all in R

Tags: r, graphics, bar-chart

I have the next problem. I'm using R Studio, but my y axis labels are not complete. I have the next code:

```
cantidad_agua <- c(24.9, 143.7, 106.7, 5.1, 28.3, 12.3, 10.4, 7.9)
usos = c("Lavado de ropa","Riego de jardín","Baño personal","Cocina","Uso piscina","Lavado de trastes","Lavado de auto","Agua para beber")

barplot(cantidad_agua, main="Diagrama de barras de agua consumida en un día", 
    xlab="Cantidad de agua consumida(Gal)", names.arg=usos,
    border="white", density=c(100, 90, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10),  
    col="darkturquoise", las=2, horiz=TRUE)
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: Just increase the size of the left margin before you plot: `par(mar= c(5, 10, 4, 2) + 0.1)` (change the 10 value to suit your taste)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with base graphics and do not want to switch to **lattice**, **ggplot2**, or whatsoever, I suggest you either deploy `par(mar = ...)` as suggested by @MrFlick in the above comments or you have a look at **grid** (in combination with **gridBase**). The latter lets you easily circumvent the clipping of y-axis labels through manually defining viewports as subsets of your current graphics device.  In the subsequent code, for instance, I create a `c("left", "bottom")` aligned `viewport` that is slightly shifted to the right (`x = .15`) and occupies 85% and 100% of the graphics window in x and y direction, respectively.

```
## load required packages
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

## start new graphics frame
plot.new()

## setup and push viewport
vp0 <- viewport(x = .15, y = 0, just = c("left", "bottom"), 
                width = .85, height = 1)
pushViewport(vp0)

## add barplot
par(new = TRUE, fig = gridFIG())

barplot(cantidad_agua, 
        main = "Diagrama de barras de \nagua consumida en un día", 
        xlab = "Cantidad de agua consumida(Gal)", names.arg = usos,
        border = "white", density = c(100, 90, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10),  
        col = "darkturquoise", las = 2, horiz = TRUE)
```

[image: barplot]

Feel free to insert a `grid.rect()` right after `pushViewport` to check the current location of the newly created `viewport`. Note the use of `par(new = TRUE, fig = gridFIG())` before inserting the actual figure to prevent `barplot` from opening a new graphics device. Also, remember to run `dev.off()` after each time you execute the above code, otherwise you will possibly run into "figure margins too large" errors sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ggplot2 as an alternative:

```
library(ggplot2)
cantidad_agua <- data.frame(v1 = c(24.9, 143.7, 106.7, 5.1, 28.3, 12.3, 10.4, 7.9), usos = c("Lavado de ropa","Riego de jardín","Baño personal","Cocina","Uso piscina","Lavado de trastes","Lavado de auto","Agua para beber"))

    g = ggplot(data = cantidad_agua, aes(x = usos, y = v1))
    g = g +  geom_bar(stat="identity")
    g = g + coord_flip()
    g
```